# How to prevent json results in MVC .net core to lowercase first letter of model properties

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, jsonresult, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

In my .net core 2.2 app when I send to client JSON results, first letters of model properties is send as lowercase.
Here is a sample:
My model looks like

```
 public class DummyModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string   Name { get; set; }
    }
```

my controller

```
 public JsonResult DummyData()
        {
            DummyModel dummyModel = new DummyModel() { Id = 1, Name = "Test" };
            return Json(dummyModel);
        }
```

Results looks like

```
{"id":1,"name":"Test"}
```

Annoying thing is that name of properties now start with first lower case.
If i simply named my properties with first letter lowercase  VS spamming me with 
[image]

Later in code I use razor for join Json results with my model and usually when I write JavaScript i simply copy / paste model to js file to define data source.
Is there a way to tell Json to not lower my properties ?